# Как создать jar-архив используя (в) Intellij idea?

Tags: java, jar, архивация

Не могу создать создать исполняемый архив JAR .Как я понял данная проблема должна решаться с помощью Terminal ,НО ОН У МЕНЯ И НЕ РАБОТАЕТ(не могу туда заносить текст,как и печатать там ,так и вставлять туда скопированный текст).Также как использовать при компиляции флаги.Также где набирать команду для создания jar-архива?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В идее сначала идете в **File | Project Structure | Artifacts**, там создаете новый **artifact**, **jar --> From modules with dependencies**

Потом **Build | Build artifacts**

Comment: К сожалению, этот способ уже неактуален

Answer (score 5):

По-хорошему у вас должна быть система сборки, которая сама этим занимается. Самые известные - это [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) и [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Кроме простой компиляции в war/jar эти системы умеют еще много полезных штук, в том числе подчищать директории от промежуточных файлов, подправлять файлы в момент компиляции, прогонять тесты и многое другое.
После этого достаточно добавить задачи в [Run Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html), и IDEA сама озаботится вызовом консольных команд, останется только запускать нужные конфигурации.