# Сборка приложения в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, gradle, ant

Для сборки Java приложений можно использовать инструменты Ant, Maven и Gradle. IntelliJ IDEA позволяет работать с этими инструментами. Но как происходит сборка по умолчанию, когда создается и запускается проект(если я не использую  Ant, Maven и Gradle)?

Comment: По умолчанию, всмысле, если создать пустой Джава проект?

Comment: вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38296/intellidjidea-%D0%B8-jar  .....еще вот  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427538/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-jar-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%B2-intellij-idea  .....и вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540/jar-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-intellij-idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сборка приложения включает в себя компиляцию, линковку и собственно упаковку кода в исполняемый файл (например, в jar-файл). Возможно, я и ошибаюсь, но, как я это понимаю, для компиляции по умолчанию IntelliJ IDEA использует обычный java-компилятор, `javac`, а для остального до запуска приложения требуется выполнить необходимые настройки - например, для использования Ant нужно указать путь к `build.xml` файлу, а для использования Maven - путь к домашней директории Maven, файлам настроек и т.д.